# How can I optimize bids and mic in reporting-services using Jenkins configuration-as-a-code?

Tags: reporting-services, bids, jenkins-confuration-as-a-code

1121 Sella
Iranian and Washington DC
Rice

Hello my problems about my company and working with this company please?
Also my deferent food from my company to people of USA .
I need test this discussion to google please.
White House
God

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read the following article and then edit your question to include all relevant information. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask